# React Native app crashing when visiting specific screen

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

**This screen works fine when testing using Expo, but crashes the app when it is bundled to apk**

I'm not sure whats causing the crash here, but it works on Expo.
This has been tested on both emulators and real android devices, which have the same behavior.

This is the error log from the device when visiting the screen:

```
04-22 10:14:11.713  7008  7008 E unknown:ReactNative: Tried to remove non-existent frame callback
04-22 10:14:11.778  1731  7439 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (101, <unspecified>/0)
04-22 10:14:11.786  7008  7065 E GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api}
04-22 10:14:11.963  7008  7008 E c       : java.lang.RuntimeException: A TaskDescription's primary color should be opaque
04-22 10:14:11.963  7008  7008 E CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics must be initialized by calling Fabric.with(Context) prior to logging exceptions.
04-22 10:14:12.023  1731  7449 E ResolverController: No valid NAT64 prefix (101, <unspecified>/0
```

And this is the respective screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import MapView from 'react-native-maps'
import { Appbar } from 'react-native-paper'

import Database from './components/Database'
const db = new Database()

import styles from './components/allStyles'

export default class MapScreen extends Component {

  state = {
    emergencies: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    db.mapOn(emergencies => {
        this.setState(previousState => ({
            emergencies: previousState.emergencies.concat(emergencies),
        }))
    })
  }

  render() {
    k = 0
    return (
      <View style={styles.absoluteFillView}>
        <MapView
          style={styles.absoluteFillView}
          mapType={"satellite"}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          region={{
            latitude: 39.625083,
            longitude:  -79.956796,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0025,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0025,
          }}
        >
          {this.state.emergencies.map(emergency => {
            if(k + 1 == this.state.emergencies.length){
              color = 'red';
            }
            else {
              color = 'orange';
            }
            return (
              <MapView.Marker 
                key = {k++}
                title={emergency.title}
                description={emergency.description}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: emergency.latitude,
                  longitude: emergency.longitude,
                }}
                pinColor={color}
              />
            );
          })}
        </MapView>
        <Appbar.Header
          dark = {true}
          style={{backgroundColor:'#bdbdbd'}}
        >
        <Appbar.Action 
          icon = 'arrow-left'
          size = {24}
            onPress={() =>{
              this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
            }}
        />
        </Appbar.Header>
      </View>
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount(){
    db.mapOff()
  }
}
```

Here are the event listener functions used in the componentDidMount() and componentWillUnmount():

```
mapOn = callback => {
    firebase.database().ref('alerts/emergency/').on('child_added', snapshot => {
        callback(this.edit(snapshot))
    })
}

mapOff = () => {
    firebase.database().ref('alerts/emergency/').off()
}

edit = snapshot => {

    const { name, description } = snapshot.val()
    const { longitude, latitude } = snapshot.val().location

    const emergency = { title: name, description, longitude, latitude}

    return emergency
}

Any help into what may be causing the issue would be very helpful.
```

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same issue,
please could you tell us if you have fixed it? thank you

Comment: @jos11 I have not, unfortunately. I can also assume its with my testing deployment service and I'm just hoping it will go away when published.